# How to map a typescript tuple into a new tuple using Array.map

Tags: typescript, tuples

I tried mapping a TypeScript Tuple into another Tuple using Array.map like so:

```js
const tuple1: [number, number, number] = [1, 2, 3];
const tuple2: [number, number, number] = tuple1.map(x => x * 2);
console.log(tuple2);
```

[TypeScript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCuAHANgUwIwC4YG0zwFsAjVAJwBoZ9izLqTSBdGAXl3UoCZKBmRgbgCwAKFCRYCFKk7Y8hBnXm0qSpqzhI06AHQEAhogAUAD1YA%20GKYBUMTgEoho8BBBptyEAHNDktPf5AA)

But the typescript compiler is telling me this is not possible:

```
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number, number]'.
Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer.
```

Is there a clean way to map a tuple into a new tuple without using Array.map or a way to use Array.map that the compiler does understand?

Comment: `tuple1.map(x => x * 2) as [number, number, number];`, but that's not ideal I guess? :)

Comment: Discovered that one already indeed. But that's cheating the compiler ;-)

Comment: Take a look at how it's done in `fp-ts`. There's a Tuple module where you can do `const z: [number,number,number] = pipe(x, tuple.map(x => x*2))` with no problems. Or `const z: [number,number,number] = tuple.map<number>(x => x*2)(x)` It's probably done with declare function overloads.

Comment: Interesting, will have a look at fp-ts @user1713450 !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript currently lacks suitable tuple method overload definitions for `map` inside `Array`.

You can globally augment the `Array` type declaration like this:

```
// important: put Array augmentation in a script/non-module file without import/export
interface Array<T> {
    // T[] | [T] enforces a tuple type.
    // {[K in keyof this]: U} keeps a mapped tuple type.
    map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, tuple: T[] | [T]) => U, thisArg?: any): {[K in keyof this]: U}
}
```

```
const t1: [number, number] = [1, 2];
const t1M = t1.map(x => x * 2); // t1M: [number, number]
const t2: [number, number, number] = [1, 2, 3];
const t2M = t2.map(String); // t2M: [string, string, string]

const t3: number[] = [1, 2, 3]
const t3M = t3.map(x => x * 2); // t3M: number[]
```

[Live code playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsFsAcHsCcAuBDAdogXKaBXRoBBeeZAT1GRwHNIBTdZRcWVCV5UAZwGN5xpEwVCwC0kWABMcAG1qgAZuFmgA7uEQALWHggwEg2gA84SALAAocOlrx5ybnKIlSAHgAqAPlABvC6H%20gIKBuANoAuqAAPqAhbhH08ggOnBSgiDjQyoik0LQAdD4hANJsoADWtKSw8mka4JxhWACqAL7ltLTQKRyQyNC5EmkZWTn5fgG90C5NHgAU3MjS0gBG9mXyqFizAG6LOLRYbgA0bBJGWKg4kMs2J%20mZB8HhUTFxAJSgALxeTXd1nEQqAB%20LBoUhvLDeYqlCpVGqaeqNUCtCwtCwWbgsTj4RAARiwIUu11uoCJN3gEU%20MVxJwATGEANwYrE43EAWS%20aVxeUms0MXy8-IAVKBaW8GYEwHi2QSySS5RTmahsWlabKruSTgqtRqbJTqXSTgBmRlKlWIWkcqkWnl9WYAZUQfFQVHFktVMpi2OdVBO3qsvq4ToDYXR5kxypxRouuvgzypIRpouNofDLLSRqtGdt0D5AtAwtFbqCiEzMeJcbCQA)

Update: If `T[] | [T]` looks too weird, you can also use variadic tuple notation (TS 4.0):

```
callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, tuple: [...this]) => U
```

[Live code playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsFsAcHsCcAuBDAdogXKaBXRoBBeeZAT1GRwHNIBTdZRcWVCV5UAZwGN5xpEwVCwC0kWABMcAG1qgAZuFmgA7uEQALWHggwEg2gA84SALAAocOlrx5ybnKIlSAHgAqAPlABvC6H%20gkMjQLgCqHgAU3MjS0gBG9gDW8qhYEQBuMTi0WG4ANGwSRlioOJBxNgWIONCyWADaAHTNmuCcALoAlKAAvF6hVRptRFQA-FhopJ1Y3vUA0mygibSksPKgrR1YoQC%20FnvmFtwsnPiIAIwNpeWVoNcV8O29oPXnBQBM7QDcRydn5wBZZ4XRpBaARQy9LyQgBUoHenS%20oBAG0BVzKDwK9xs7V%20qFOG3e6Ju8CxGNu2Mez1eHwKAGZvniCYh3kCeoTQcEIgBlRB8VBURHIsAsgENU78qgFCVWKVcPmy3GHczHfFnOklcnwepPdk0%20H0pWq5l0tkbOmc8GQvqgWHwoUoxCmzUknUWJlnAAs4oVArJJIKcVgsFkaCe1IARMgIwU3ht4NklSjQBobHI0KAjMgYMo1oEEHJjjmjBtSNBaB6Np6zYhPZaIVDS%20W89aeuyI5SI6BRrbQHD3qAsIgy7QW7026AI0GQ7Q0F2ewA5LUQ6a2xqyAWaB0i513LU6oA)